# How to reset icon in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I added an EditText element to my ActionBar in an android program.  When the icon is clicked, the EditText element appears and data is entered and captured when the return or enter key is struck.  How can I make the EditText element disappear and have the icon re-appear?  Currently, the EditText field remains in the ActionBar and the icon is hidden.  Below is my menu xml file.  Any help is appreciated.

```
       <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/herbsearch"
    android:title="HerbSearch"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    />
   <item
    android:id="@+id/locationchange"
    android:title="Change Location"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
    />
```

And here is my EditText layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_search"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:hint="Enter new location"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
/>
```

And below is my onCreateOptionsMenu logic.

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    /** Get the action view of the menu item whose id is search */
    View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.locationchange).getActionView();

    /** Get the edit text from the action view */
    EditText locSearch = ( EditText ) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
    locSearch.requestFocus();
    /** Setting an action listener */
    locSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        //    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Search : " + v.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            GetMap(String.valueOf(v.getText()));
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

            /** Get the edit text from the action view */
            EditText locSearch = ( EditText ) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_search);

        // I tried these next 3 instructions with no success
        //   locSearch.setVisibility(1);   

         //  v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        //   v.setVisibility(1);
            return false;

        }
    });
   }
```

Comment: If you think my answer is correct then please accept it as the correct one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    final MenuItem locationItem = menu.findItem(R.id.locationchange);
    View v = (View) locationItem.getActionView();
    EditText locSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
    locSearch.requestFocus();

    locSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || (event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                locationItem.collapseActionView();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I added the line final MenuItem locationItem = menu.findItem(R.id.locationchange); to retrieve the location change menu item and I'm calling locationItem.collapseActionView(); to get rid of the action view / search view.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for the suggestion.  I inserted the final MenuItem locationItem = menu.findItem(R.id.locationchange); instruction in the onCreateOptionsMenu method but just added the location.Item.collapseActionView(); instruction right before I called GetMap in the OnEditorActionListener method.  If I entered it

Comment: Sorry for the last comment screwup.  To repeat - Thanks for the suggestion.  I inserted your routine after the call to GetMap() and it worked just like I wanted.  I knew I had to call collapseActionView but I didn't know how to get the menuitem as I am still a newbie.  You guys are saving my life at Stack Overflow.

Comment: You're welcome. How about marking the answer as correct then ? ;-)